# jquery dialog to fit mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an html page that will fit Mobile and desktop browser 
I have jquery dialog that I want to scale that will fit the page I am asuming that the problem 
are in these line

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ minWidth: minW,minHeight: minH });
$("#dialog").dialog().position({ my: 'center', at: 'center', of: '#base' });
```

[here is the page](http://isra-build.com/)

Comment: are you sure about position parameters?

Comment: I am not an expert in that so I am not sure what are you suggesting

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it should look like but,

> **.position()** 
>   Returns: Object. Description: Get the current coordinates
>   of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the
>   offset parent.
>   This method does not accept any
>   arguments.
>   http://api.jquery.com/position/

try to modify last line in such way:

```
$("#dialog").css({ left: '20%', top: '2%' }); //play with percentage
```